# How do i unzip a zip file in nodejs without using adm-zip?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a file xyz.zip and i wanted to unzip this file and read contents in a node.j, however i wanted to this by using just basic modules(fs, readFileStream and) and avoid using adm-zip etc.

Any help?

Comment: You need to use zip library unless you want to implement zip algorythm yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 'zlib' inbuilt module of Nodejs.

var zlib = require('zlib')

Read more about the api from https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/zlib.html#zlib_zlib

Comment: zlib does not support zip files from what i read? Can you please confirm?

Comment: They support, use deflate api or create a unzip class object and use the api. Read and try with deflate option for start and then dig deeper